# Keep highlighted filter of a hidden Matrix visualization using bookmarks

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem using bookmark tabs to alternate between different matrix tables.

When I highlight one record of Table A and use the bookmark to hide Table A and display another one (table B), the filter (highlight on Table A) disappears.

I tried using DAX measures, but the value change when I hide the MatriX element

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when the visibility changes the highlighted selection is reset.
A couple of suggestions:

1. Instead of hiding Table A, try having a white (or matching background colour) rectangle that covers Table A. Then update your bookmarks to show/hide the rectangle cover with Table B.
2. Other option is use drillthrough to a new page - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough